# Improve sqlite performance

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have online application, it's using sqlite database, it's containing few tables, one table containing 760k items, other tables containing 3-4k records. All tables have indexes.

I write something in database each 10 seconds. All is good, before i have few visitors on my online app, it's start work really slow, sometimes it return result of query from 760k items table in 20-30 seconds. It's not effect small tables, but only this large table.

Example of table:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, number INT NOT NULL, timestamp INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(20), views BIGINT NOT NULL,  data BINARY(128) NOT NULL, previousRecord VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, , FOREIGN KEY ( previousRecord ) REFERENCES records ( id ) ON DELETE SET NULL)",
```

Indexes:

```
"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS records_number ON records(number)",

"CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS records_name ON records(name)"
```

Query than i ran contains joins to other 2-3 tables. When i insert in table i use transaction.

Example of my query:

```
SELECT r.id, r.number, r.name, r.views, lower(hex(r.data)),
 r.previousRecord, it.id, it.type, it.recordId, lower(hex(it.data)) 
FROM 
  (select * from records limit 100 offset 100) as r  
   left outer join items as it on it.recordId=r.id
```

I'm interesting what i can do to improve perfomance on my select requests. Maybe i need to change configuration of sqlite? Or i have some hidden rocks?

Comment: You need to show the queries in your question, if you want any advice on performance.

Comment: "sometimes it just can't return result" - are there any messages when it happens?

Comment: I will update with queries.

Comment: It can run result, but in 20-30 seconds.

Comment: **UPD**: i updated post with my query

Comment: Show the table definition, including indexes, for all tables used in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting offset and limit but you are not ordering the result , why ? in what order do you want this limit and offset ?

Can you convert your record_id ( VARCHAR ) somehow to integer ? it will be much faster to compare integers

You must create an index on items.recordId , because you are using that field to join to records table ,

1. try creating index on items.record

try using this query , and change order clause if you want different sorting

```
SELECT  r.id, 
        r.number, 
        r.name, 
        r.views, 
        lower(hex(r.data)),
        r.previousRecord, 
        it.id, 
        it.type, 
        it.recordId, 
        lower(hex(it.data)) 
FROM 
    records r
    left outer join items as it on it.recordId = r.id
    order by r.id 
    limit 100 offset 100
```

Comment: yes, i have index on recordId. I can't convert record_id to VARCHAR, because there is very very big number (BIGINT is not enough).

Comment: Looks like problem was in this subquery: (select * from records limit 100 offset 100) , i removed it and reduced execution from 67ms to 7ms. Anyway thanks for help!